# android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-context

I'm trying to call a service class from another service class but I get this error:

> android.content.Context.getPackageName() on a null object reference

Do you know how I call service from another service?

When I setup my app to phone first, a broadcastreceiver is starting Alarm class and in Alarm class, I want to start another service in ReadGmail() method. But I get that null object reference error.

Here is my code:

```
public class Alarm extends Service {
private String userName;
private String password;
private String receivingHost;
Context context;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                     String senderPassword=new String("password");
                        String senderUserName=new String("username@gmail.com");
                        Alarm newGmailClient=new Alarm();
                        newGmailClient.setAccountDetails(senderUserName, senderPassword);
                        newGmailClient.readGmail();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 10, 120000);

     return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


  };



public void setAccountDetails(String userName,String password){  
    this.userName=userName;//sender's email can also use as User Name
    this.password=password;
}


public void readGmail(){
    this.receivingHost="imap.gmail.com";//for imap protocol
    Properties props2=System.getProperties();
    props2.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Session session2=Session.getInstance(props2, null);
        try {
                Store store=session2.getStore("imaps");
                store.connect(this.receivingHost,this.userName, this.password);
                Folder folder=store.getFolder("INBOX");//get inbox
                folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);//open folder only to read
                Message message[]=folder.getMessages();
                String key= "Hey";
                String subject;
                for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(message[i].getSubject());
                    subject=message[i].getSubject();

                 if(subject.equals(key)){
                     System.out.println("inside");
Intent mTutorial = new Intent(Alarm.this, LaunchActivity.class); 

this.startService(mTutorial); 

//I want to call service class in here. LaunchActivity is my service class.



                 }
                    //Log.d(message[i].getSubject(),message[i].getSubject());
                }
                folder.close(true);
                store.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void onDestroy() {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("", "FirstService destroyed");
}


}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Reading mails first and ..
10-23 18:14:00.077: I/System.out(31965): inside
10-23 18:14:00.077: I/System.out(31965): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
10-23 18:14:00.078: I/Choreographer(31965): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-23 18:14:00.155: I/Timeline(31965): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@297f59e8 time:24716923

Comment: That isn't the full stacktrace. Don't filter your logcat you might be missing something iimportant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Alarm newGmailClient=new Alarm();
```

Your `Alarm` class extends `Service`. It is an Android `Service`. You cannot create an instance of an Android component with `new`. Only Android can create Android components. If you want to start a `Service`, you call `startService`.

Why do you want to start another `Service`? Please explain.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This is the solution. My another service has two classes, locationlistener and also it's doing too much work so it has a lot of code. Because of that I wanted to call another service. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface your Service will use to communicate events:

public interface ServiceCallbacks {
    void doSomething();
}

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What must I do?